# Dynamically adding style to form ? Using Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In web application, I am trying to add style to form, I write like this :

```
 form1.Attributes.CssStyle.Add ("style","background:url(nEWmOSIACH.jpg)");
```

but i am not getting any image, can you help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it , i write the code in form oninit event , now it is coming.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the generated html and, most importantly, the given path using dev tools in your browser. This should be working. My guess is a wrong path to the image...

Comment: Hi walther, when i given the code to div it is working fine but change code like : dv.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("background", "url(nEWmOSIACH.jpg)");

Comment: i think form is already loaded, that is y i am not getting, actually i write the code in page load.